# Java not returning value

Tags: java

If I could get a explanation of the issue and the proper code, I would really appreciate it.

```
public class functiond {

    public static double itemCount = 1.99;
    public static double dollarsProvided = 2.00;

    public static double makeChange(double itemCount, double dollarsProvided) {
        double change = dollarsProvided - itemCount;
        return change;
    }
    public static double main(String[] args) {
        makeChange(1.99, 2.00);
    }
}
```

Just want it to print out "change".

Comment: `public double main(String[] args)` --> `public void main(String[] args)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a basic tutorial service. There are plenty of those out there already. I'm sure that a quick google of your error message will come up with a boatload of duplicate questions.

Comment: I am beginner and have as much right as anyone else to use this service. I will continue to post my questions regardless of there simplicity.

Comment: @Push1 Please do continue, nobody is suggesting otherwise.  Have a good day.

Comment: If you are receiving an error you should tell us what the error is.

Comment: @Charles M, actually the error no long appears, i,ve modified the question. Now the issue is that the "change" isn't printing out in the terminal. No more errors

Comment: Which line of code did you think was going to print the word change? Which line of code did you think would print anything?

Comment: Sorry not the word change but its value, i assume line 8 should once the function is run.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning value but you are not printing it.

As you are declaring itemCount and dollarsProvided globally you don't need to pass them as parameter.

```
public class functiond {

    public static double itemCount = 1.99;
    public static double dollarsProvided = 2.00;

    public static double makeChange() {
        double change = dollarsProvided - itemCount;
        return change;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(makeChange());
    }
}
```

Comment: Than you very much Sir, my vote would have displayed but unfortunately a couple bad question can have a impact on ones reputation which effects my votes fro being visible. Thank you again.